# Translate keystrokes into MIDI Input events

Tags: midi

I am currently struggling with the following: How Can I translate a keystroke into a MIDI Event in Linux? I am working with Linuxmint 20.3 Cinnamon The context: I have an USB footswitch (which is perceived as a keyboard by the OS) and want to us it as a sustain-pedal. I was wondering if I can do this with a script.

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you mean your footswich is not a midi compatible device ? (I mean in no way capable to send midi events on whatever serial link ?) In which case, I would suggest you give some attention to the Linux pseudoMidi Input project : http://lsmi-all.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hey, thank you for the hint! I checked it out. To me it seems like the specific script needs a lot of costumisation for my case. Anyways, it inspired me to work on a python script for this.

Comment: You may need to install a driver to have it working as a MIDI device. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/709142/edit) your question with the exact model of the device